# Why isn't my if statement function populating my variable (C)?

Tags: c

My if statement works in terms of control flow- i.e. it catches the condition and executes or passes accordingly (the second if statement below). However, when I call the compiled program with the value 2 `./bankers.c 2`, the value of num_processes reverts to 0 and prints 0 to console, as opposed to 2. When I uncomment the second call to that function, outside of if(), then it works. Shouldn't it populate the variable no matter what as that function is being called? I know you can call the fork() function inside the if statement. This is more a theory question.

```
int num_processes = 1;
if (argv[1] == NULL)
{
    printf("Please enter an integer command line argument between 1 and 20 (exiting)\n\n");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    char *remainder;
    if (num_processes = strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10) < 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please request 1 or more processes (exiting)\n");
        return 2;
    }
    // num_processes = strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10);
    printf("Rest of string: %s\n", remainder);
}
printf("Num processes %u\n", num_processes);
```

Comment: `num_processes = strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10) < 1` is the same as `num_processes = (strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10) < 1)`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (num_processes = strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10) < 1)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (num_processes = (strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10) < 1))
```

When what you probably want is

```
if ((num_processes = strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10)) < 1)
```

Or, better yet, do the assignment outside of the `if` to reduce the confusion:

```
num_processes = strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10);
if (num_processes < 1)
```

By the way, your compiler can probably warn you about this being confusing if you increase the warning options. With `-Wall` for gcc for example:

```
<source>:16:9: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
   16 |     if (num_processes = strtol(argv[1], &remainder, 10) < 1)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot of sense now- it was evaluating to false and that was the value being assigned num_processes -i.e. 0. Parenthesis control what evaluates to what. And yes that -Wall helps too. I'm going to start using that more.